# Pandas Timestamp strangely omitting ms, us and nanoseconds

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp-with-timezone

I am using Pandas to obtain EPOCH timestamps, i.e. nanoseconds since January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT), from human-friendly data/time input. Everything was fine until I recently updated the Anaconda environment. Now, I do not understand if I made a mistake (high probability) or there is maybe a bug in the update package.

Until the recent rounds of updates the following sequence of commands produced an integer number giving the EPOCH time in nanoseconds:

```
ts = pd.Timestamp('2021-04-25 12:13:30', tz='Europe/Berlin')
ts_new = np.int64(ts.asm8)
```

> 1619345610000000000

However, now the result is simply

> 1619345610

It looks like since I did not bother to give milliseconds, microseconds, and nanoseconds, these are now omitted instead of assumed to be zero. However, according to the Pandas documentation asm8 should "Return numpy datetime64 format in nanoseconds." This is clearly not the case now.

What did I do wrong? Or might this be a bug?

Addendum:

```
ts = pd.to_datetime('2021-04-25 12:13:30')
ts_new = np.int64(ts.asm8)
```

> 1619352810000000000

So, this still works as expected. But here I am missing the functionality to define a timezone and let Pandas take care of everything else.

P.S. Here is the output of pd.show_version().

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit           : 0f437949513225922d851e9581723d82120684a6
python           : 3.11.3.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Windows
OS-release       : 10
Version          : 10.0.19045
machine          : AMD64
processor        : Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
byteorder        : little
LC_ALL           : None
LANG             : en
LOCALE           : de_DE.cp1252

pandas           : 2.0.3
numpy            : 1.24.3
pytz             : 2022.7
dateutil         : 2.8.2
setuptools       : 67.8.0
pip              : 23.1.2
Cython           : None
pytest           : 7.4.0
hypothesis       : None
sphinx           : 5.0.2
blosc            : None
feather          : None
xlsxwriter       : None
lxml.etree       : 4.9.2
html5lib         : None
pymysql          : None
psycopg2         : None
jinja2           : 3.1.2
IPython          : 8.15.0
pandas_datareader: None
bs4              : 4.12.2
bottleneck       : 1.3.5
brotli           : 
fastparquet      : None
fsspec           : 2023.4.0
gcsfs            : None
matplotlib       : 3.7.2
numba            : 0.57.1
numexpr          : 2.8.4
odfpy            : None
openpyxl         : 3.0.10
pandas_gbq       : None
pyarrow          : None
pyreadstat       : None
pyxlsb           : None
s3fs             : 2023.4.0
scipy            : 1.11.1
snappy           : 
sqlalchemy       : 1.4.39
tables           : 3.8.0
tabulate         : 0.8.10
xarray           : 2023.6.0
xlrd             : None
zstandard        : 0.19.0
tzdata           : 2023.3
qtpy             : 2.2.0
pyqt5            : None
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to check which versions were installed previously (before the update).

Comment: `Until the recent rounds of updates` Since this could be related to a package update, can you provide the version of Pandas which worked before the update, and the version that is causing problems?

Comment: For completeness, the values for `ts.asm8` I get are `numpy.datetime64('2021-04-25T10:13:30')` and `numpy.datetime64('2021-04-25T12:13:30.000000000')` respectively.

Comment: I think this is a bug. Might be related to this change [from the Pandas 2.0 release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#other-api-changes): *"Passing a `np.datetime64` object with non-nanosecond resolution to `Timestamp` will retain the input resolution if it is “s”, “ms”, “us”, or “ns”; otherwise it will be cast to the closest supported resolution (GH 49008)"*

Comment: @NickODell I updated the original post with the version information.

Comment: @wjandrea I submitted a bug report on the Github page of PANDAS. However, I am not sure if providing the datetime string without explicitly stating seconds, milliseconds, etc. is not a failure on my side. But it would be a pain in the ass if this was really necessary now.